# User is retagging all sorts of posts with [internet-explorer-7]

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

The user [Josh Unger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646752/josh-unger) has been submitting a ton of suggested edits, where the only change is to add the `internet-explorer-7` tag to questions that mention IE7. This is being done without addressing any other concerns in the questions.

Normally when someone asks or answers a question poorly, I am able to comment and try to help them out. I am not sure how to contact this user to help them recognize that they need to do more thorough and careful edits.

So, I'm asking this question: What can be done about such a user?

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: 16 edits per day, for the last 3 days. Damn impressive speeds.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well, all of his edits are very minor. Since the guy clearly wants to edit (either to help the site or get a badge), it would be nice if he were making larger, more constructive edits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Would this not be consider a "too  minor" edit?

Comment: If you feel that his edits are insubstantial, reject them as too minor.  That's all, thank you.  Nothing more to see here, move along.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That sounds like a perfectly reasonable response. Worth an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Just to confirm: he gets no rep for retagging (provided he doesn't edit the content)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across these edits too. All these posts are found with a search for *ie7* easily, and given the stats, they are rarely relevant anymore.

Good tagging is important. But ignoring even basic things like *Thanks* and similar noise doesn’t help. Reject too minor edits as too minor, that’s why this reject reason exists. Or, even better, improve the posts. :)